# Python GUI scale

Tags: python, user-interface, scale

How can I do it, that when I push the scale to 3, then push a button and something special happens then? So that I define an action for every variable in the scale. I tried it with if, but it's not working. There is no error. The labels just dont appear. Thanks.

```
from tkinter import *
mode2f=Tk()

def antmenge(self):
        möant["text"]="Mögliche Antworten: " \
            + str(antmengen.get()) + " "

möant=Label(mode2f, text="Mögliche Antworten: 0 Wörter", width=25)
möant.pack()

antmengen=IntVar()
antmengen.set(0)

antm=Scale(mode2f, width=20, length=200, orient="vertical", from_=0, to=1,
resolution=1, tickinterval=10, label="Wörter", command=antmenge,
variable=antmengen)
antm.pack()

def antmengenask():
    if antmengen==0:
        label=Label(mode2f, text="0")
        label.pack()
    elif antmengen==1:
        label1=Label(mode2f, text="1")
        label1.pack()

button=Button(mode2f, text="push", command=antmengenask)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `antmengen.get()` to get value.

BTW: don't use native chars in variable names (`ö` in `möant`)